# document_scanner_flutter' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i am using this plugin document_scanner_flutter: ^0.2.7 in my flutter mobile application for scanning the document but issue i am facing in this library is not compatible with latest kotlin version when i try to integrate and run my project i am getting this error below.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':document_scanner_flutter' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

any expert is here who know how to update this library for flutter because their developer is not updating this library and i am beginner i don't know how to update it

Comment: any one has solution for this I'm also having same issue.

Comment: i have the same issue, i tried with updating     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
min and max sdk but failed.